# How to create a friction-based cable exercise machine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, friction

What would be the best mechanism to create a friction based cable machine? The point of this machine to only have resistance to movement not when the cable's stationary and without the momentum of ordinary cable machines in explosive movements. When the movement stops it should just stay still with very little force pulling back on it

I thought about applying the friction based mechanism from a cycling machine to a reel of cable but I believe that would require the a large diameter wheel(heavier causing the cable to have momentum). Is the there another better way to do this? It there a way to add friction with tension wheels along the cable?

Comment: Drive a fan. Classic solution.

Comment: Nice. Serious answers please.

Comment: I was being serious.

Comment: @SolarMike is correct. The power a fan requires increases with the cube of the speed. (Check that I'm correct on this.) That makes it a good choice. Better still is to generate electricity and do something useful with the energy.

Comment: Thanks but a fan wouldn't be a good fit for this. The resistance shouldn't be related to the speed and it wouldn't work well in a cable machine application

Comment: Check out dynamometers, but you might not know if any are a good fit.

Comment: I guess a brake applied to a spool would be the best way

Comment: I actually found a company that makes pneumatic cable machines but the weights don't go up very high. Maybe using hydraulics could increase things

Comment: It sounds like you want it to essentially lock into place when someone isn't pulling on it. If that's right, what you need is a dead man's switch on the handle (like on a lawn mower) which holds a brake open.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stirring air or water like suggested in the comments you could stir a bunch of beads or powder. That way the torque wouldn't change with speed and also wouldn't have much inertia. Could be fully submerged rotary vanes, or partially submerged or perhaps even a corkscrew.

I would think the ideal grain size would be typical to that of playground sand because at that size there is enough surface area that if you wet it with oil like mineral oil or baby oil to turns into a thick slurry to stir which seems ideal. I wouldn't actually use sand though because it is so abrasive. Anything finer than playground sand (about 36-grit by my estimate) is probably too fine.

If you go with larger particles such that they are more like beads or ball bearings  you'll probably still want some oil in there to assist in lubrication and to capture dust from wear.

It's going to be loud though unless you the beads are maybe coated in plastic or somehow otherwise made to be able to deform slightly without sticking to itself.

Friction brakes applied to a spool is sort of like a prony brake, and from experience I can tell you they aren't as straightforward to make such that they operate consistently and smoothly as they initially appear. They can also screech.

Comment: Interesting take. The weights would have to be adjustable in precise increments just like a regular cable machine so don't think powders or beads would work for this. And I don't have much experience with brakes but the brakes on my motorcycle are as smooth as butter and don't screech. Figure that could be scaled down and any inconsistency could be solved with sanding the calipers and rotors to an ideal grit

Comment: @bacon_is_good I suppose you could use a variable AOA rotor to adjust torque.  Your car brakes might not screech but those use materials that you don't have access to and have lots of engineering behind them.

Comment: With powders I think there'd be a big difference as the speed changes because of "turbulence". And there's gotta be a company that makes nice mini brake calipers, and the rotors and brake pad materials could be precisely ground at any machining shop

Comment: @bacon_is_good You don't get turbulence in solids,. Even a fluid would work so long as you managed to find a fluid where the viscosity of the fluid was much greater than the inertial forces in the fluid which is what having a bunch of fine particles tries to simulate.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use an electric generator with an adjustable load. Control the load using feedback from a loadcell and you can create a constant resistance force at any speed (above some minimum). The feedback could be very fast because it's all electronic.

To illustrate my point, if you take a generator and short out the output, you will find that it's very difficult to turn. Imagine this as the default state of your machine. The user pulls on the cable a and the generator resists this strongly. Meanwhile a load cell is positioned to measure the force. When it reaches the desired setpoint, the "short" on the generator is removed and the motor "slips" a tiny bit (like mm's), moving easily until the force goes back under the threshold. Do this very fast, and it will just feel like a constant resistance.

Comment: Nice idea, I believe this is similar to what Tonal's system does